# Why i can not run the bcp command in command prompt?

Tags: sql-server

I'm beginner in sql server,want to write simple bcp command in command prompt to copy table data into the text file , i write this:

```
bcp myTABLE out f:\example.txt -S DESKTOP-A5CFJSH\MSSQLSERVER1 -T
```

but i get this error:
[image]

and my table path in sql server is this:
[image]

how can i solve that?thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `bcp myTestReport.dbo.myTABLE out f:\example.txt -S DESKTOP-A5CFJSH\MSSQLSERVER1 -T` instead.

Comment: excuse me ,when i run that query, ask me for example enter id storage type,what this?

Comment: You can find more info at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189110.aspx `The file storage type describes how data is stored in the data file. Data can be exported to a data file as its database table type (native format), in its character representation (character format), or as any data type where implicit conversion is supported; for example, copying a smallint as an int. User-defined data types are exported as their base types.`